# How to solve Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined for checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

```js
var html = ''
var allseat = []
let allS = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
var emp = db.collection('BookedTicketData').get().then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
    data = doc.data();
    bseat = data.AllSeat
    // console.log(bseat)  //(2) [33, 34]
    allseat = allseat.concat(bseat)
  })

  console.log(allseat)
  return allseat;
}).then((s) => {
  allS.filter(n => {
    if (n !== 33) {
      if (n % 2 != 0 && n != 1) {
        html += `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`
      }
      if (s.includes(n)) {
        console.log("n -> " + n)
        console.log("s -> " + s) // s -> 33,34
        html += `<input type="checkbox" class="dn checkme" name="s-size" id="${n}" value="${n}" disabled/>
                         <label for="${n}" class="col-2 br-pill f7 m-1 btn text-white bg-danger border-danger grow" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Seat Already Booked" disabled>${n}</label>
            
                         `
      } else {
        html += ` <input type="checkbox" class="dn checkme" name="s-size" id="${n}"  value="${n}"/>
                         <label for="${n}" class="col-2 br-pill f7 m-1 btn text-dark bg-white border-dark           grow">${n}</label>
            
                       `
      }
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('loader').innerHTML = html;

  //Note: Add change events after setting the html into the DOM.

  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
    let id = $(this).attr("id");
    let checkbox = document.getElementById(id);
    // console.log("C->" + id)
    let checkbox_label = $(`[for=${id}]`);
    // console.log("CL->" + checkbox_label)

    if (checkbox_label.hasClass('bg-dark')) {
      // console.log('Hii')
      checkbox_label.removeClass('text-white')
      checkbox_label.addClass('text-dark')
      checkbox_label.removeClass('bg-dark')
      checkbox_label.addClass('bg-white')
    } else {
      // console.log('Bye')
      checkbox_label.removeClass('text-dark')


      checkbox_label.addClass('text-white')
      checkbox_label.removeClass('bg-white')
      checkbox_label.addClass('bg-dark')
    }
  });

})
```

```html
<div class="row flex flex-row justify-center items-center">
  <div class="col-11">
    <form id="form1" method="post"></form>
    <div id="loader" class="row flex-row flex justify-center mt3 mb4 py-2 f7 items-center vh-auto overflow-auto border-dark ba b--washed-green">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" style="background-color: teal; color: white;" onclick="validate(33)" class="btn roberto-btn w-100">Enter Traveller Details</button>
      <div id="demo" class="collapse">
        <div id="displayer" class="row flex-row flex justify-center mt3 mb4 py-2 f7 items-center vh-50 overflow-auto border-dark ba b--red">
          <div class="card card-body " id="cust-data">
            <!-- Customer Data -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have taken the value from firebase and showing the checkbox according to them and after that i have made a button named "Enter Traveller Details" which is doing the task of counting the checkboxes which checkbox is marked or not and according to that displaying the form how many checkboxes are selected. But i am getting a problem that the button i have made "Enter Traveller Details" onclick i have applied a function and that validate(33)

```
let validate = (num) => {
let checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checkme');
console.log(checks); 
let html = '';
let count = 0;
for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  if (checks[i].checked === true) {
      console.log("Value -> " + checks[i].value)
      count++;
  } else {
      // console.log("Not ->" + i)
  }
}
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  html += `
      <form class="customer-validation">

          <div class="customer-datas">
          <div class="f7 customer-data" >
          <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-end">
  <div class="col-6 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
      <label for="Name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control   cust-name"  name="name"
          placeholder="Name" >
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
      <label for="Age">Age</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control  cust-age"  name="age"
          placeholder="Age">

  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
      <label for="Gender">Gender</label><br>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
     <input type="checkbox"  class="cust-male" value="Male"> Male
  </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
     <input  class="cust-female" type="checkbox"  value="Female"> Female
  </label>

    </div>
 </div>
 <br>

      </div>
      <hr />
      </div>
      </form>
  `
   }
    html += `
      <button id="payment-button" type="submit" style="background-color: teal; color: white;" 
    onclick="printData()" class="btn roberto-btn w-100">Book your Ticket</button>

   `
    document.getElementById("cust-data").innerHTML = html;
  }
```

This function is executing but it is giving an error Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined [image]

Comment: Why `i < num` and not `i < checks.length`? Also, be aware that `document.getElementsByClassName` is a HTMLCollection which is **live** updating when the DOM changes.

Comment: Please also note that you keep overwriting `document.getElementById("cust-data").innerHTML = html;` because you do that *inside* the loop.